# NumPy data type comparison

Tags: python, numpy, types

I was playing with comparing data types of two different arrays to pick one that is suitable for combining the two. I was happy to discover that I could perform comparison operations, but in the process discovered the following strange behavior:

```
In [1]: numpy.int16 > numpy.float32
Out[1]: True

In [2]: numpy.dtype('int16') > numpy.dtype('float32')
Out[2]: False
```

Can anyone explain what is going on here?  This is NumPy 1.8.2.

Comment: Incidentally, I ended up discovering and using `np.find_common_type` but I'm still interested in what was going on here. Thanks!

Comment: I'm using `numpy` 1.9.2 on Windows, and both comparisons return `False`. As in the answer below, this is meaningless, and has been removed in Python 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first comparison is not meaningful, the second *is* meaningful.

With `numpy.int16 > numpy.float32` we are comparing two `type` objects:

```
>>> type(numpy.int16)
type
>>> numpy.int16 > numpy.float32 # I'm using Python 3
TypeError: unorderable types: type() > type()
```

In Python 3 this comparison fails immediately since there is no defined ordering for `type` instances. In Python 2, a boolean is returned but cannot be relied upon for consistency (it falls back to comparing memory addresses or other implementation-level stuff).

The second comparison *does* work in Python 3, and it works consistently (same in Python 2). This is because we're now comparing `dtype` instances:

```
>>> type(numpy.dtype('int16'))
numpy.dtype
>>> numpy.dtype('int16') > numpy.dtype('float32')
False
>>> numpy.dtype('int32') < numpy.dtype('|S10')
False
>>> numpy.dtype('int32') < numpy.dtype('|S11')
True
```

What's the logic behind this ordering?

`dtype` instances are ordered according to whether one can be cast (safely) to another. One type is *less than* another if it can be *safely cast* to that type.

For the implementation of the comparison operators, look at [descriptor.c](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/descriptor.c); specifically at the [`arraydescr_richcompare`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/descriptor.c#l3451) function.

Here's what the `<` operator maps to:

```
switch (cmp_op) {
 case Py_LT:
        if (!PyArray_EquivTypes(self, new) && PyArray_CanCastTo(self, new)) {
            result = Py_True;
        }
        else {
            result = Py_False;
        }
        break;
```

Essentially, NumPy just checks that the two types are (i) not equivalent, and (ii) that the first type can be cast to the second type.

This functionality is also exposed in the NumPy API as [`np.can_cast`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.can_cast.html):

```
>>> np.can_cast('int32', '|S10')
False
>>> np.can_cast('int32', '|S11')
True
```

Answer (score 3):

It's nothing interesting. Python 2 tries to provide consistent but meaningless comparison results for objects that don't define how to compare themselves with each other. The developers decided that was a mistake, and in Python 3, these comparisons will raise a `TypeError`.

Comment: The second comparison does *not* fail in Python 3 and it's not correct to imply it is meaningless (as the first comparison is). It is to do with whether one type can be cast to another. (I've added an answer explaining this.)

Comment: @ajcr: Huh. I must admit I didn't actually check the documentation, but now that I've looked, I don't see any comparison for dtypes documented anywhere. The source matches what you describe, but is this behavior we're allowed to rely on, or is it something that might change without notice? Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: I also couldn't find any documentation describing this use of comparison operators, or even any exchanges on the relevant mailing lists. It seems it's just one of those corners of the library which hasn't been documented yet. I'm not sure if the developers will change the behaviour in future releases, but I've certainly not seen it used much before. Functions like `can_cast` seem a much clearer and more flexible way to compare dtypes.