# Select type with higher precision

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-dtype

Function `common_precision` takes two numpy arrays, say `x` and `y`. I want to make sure that they are in the same and the highest precision. It seems that relational comparison of dtypes does something to what I want, but:

1. I don't know what it actually compares
2. It thinks that `numpy.int64` < `numpy.float16`, which I'm not sure if I agree

```
    def common_precision(x, y):
        if x.dtype > y.dtype:
           y = y.astype(x.dtype)
        else:
           x = x.astype(y.dtype)
        return (x, y)
```

Edited:
Thanks to kennytm's answer I found that NumPy's `find_common_type` does exactly what I wanted.

```
    def common_precision(self, x, y):        
        dtype = np.find_common_type([x.dtype, y.dtype], [])
        if x.dtype != dtype: x = x.astype(dtype)
        if y.dtype != dtype: y = y.astype(dtype)       
        return x, y
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x.dtype > y.dtype` means `y.dtype` [can be casted to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29710045/numpy-data-type-comparison) `x.dtype` (`&& x.dtype != y.type`), so:

```
>>> numpy.dtype('i8') < numpy.dtype('f2')
False
>>> numpy.dtype('i8') > numpy.dtype('f2')
False
```

float16 and int64 are simply incompatible. You could extract some information like:

```
>>> numpy.dtype('f2').kind
'f'
>>> numpy.dtype('f2').itemsize
2
>>> numpy.dtype('i8').kind
'i'
>>> numpy.dtype('i8').itemsize
8
```

and determine your comparison scheme based on this.

Comment: This did not entirely solve my question, but your answer and your link got me on the correct path. Thanks!